# Scrape data from an ill-formed pdf table

Tags: html, css, regex, python-2.7, pdf

I am trying to scrape data from a poorly laid out pdf (URL in the following code). I will need  to use information about the position of the lines/borders of the table to make meaningful data records.

```
url="http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/Lists/CMC%20%20PublicaesFicheiros/Attachments/89/Lista%20de%20Institui%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20Registadas%20(actualizado%2004.07.16).pdf"

import scraperwiki, urllib2, re
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
xml=scraperwiki.pdftoxml(u.read()) # interpret pdf as xml
```

The lines of XML don’t indicate how the table-lines break up the information. A typical line looks like this:

```
<text top="678" left="493" width="103" height="12" font="6">Besa Património </text>
```

In my browser’s element inspector, the HTML is slightly more detailed but I still don’t see information about the placement of the table-lines.

I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to deal with this and so I would appreciate it if any speculative answers are tried out first.The question is, how do I get the position of the table-lines?

Comment: This is a [tagged PDF](https://pdftables.com/upload/view/x1ho0izxoubk977uyzcopiytx/Lista%20de%20Institui%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20Registadas%20%28actualizado%2004.07.16%29.pdf)

Comment: My main concern is that it has lost the information about how the first column groups together the 39 records. It might be useful to get the pdf into this form, can I output a tagged pdf through Python?

Comment: Trying to get information from a repeatable, known PDF structure is possible (maybe), trying to get it from *any* PDF is almost, if not impossible. Get the original data.

Comment: What do you mean by a known PDF structure? The question is about how the lines of a pdf table are represented in programmatic form.

Answer (score 0):

to get the borders of the table you need to:

- decompress PDF and iterate through objects (not sure but maybe [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/) will work to iterate through [objects](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/#ordinary-objects))
- search for lines and rectangles inside PDF. This particular PDF represents lines as the following rectangles (4 values followed by the `re` command):

`270.17 749.85 182.81 20.67 re`

or

`270.17 414.16 182.81 20.76 re`

If you manage to decompress the PDF (with [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/) or another tool) then you may try to make a simple parser or maybe just run regular expressions against all objects to:

- collect all rectangles
- group rectangles by similar X and Y coordinates
- find coordinates of X and Y borders
- finally match text snippets against particular column or row boundaries (note that Y coordinate is inverted in PDF, see [pdf specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf))

This is basically how [ByteScout PDF Multitool](https://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html) utility (unfortunately works on Windows only) and others work